# Struggling to login to my Facebook account

Tags: facebook, email-confirmation

Am trying to log into my account,but firstly I need to get a confirmation code sent to my number by text to do so.i haven't received any code even though it is my correct number that it should be texted to.what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

How many time did you tried to resend the confirmation code?
If you done it more than 3 times.

Try again after 24hours. After you get logged in, make sure to setup 2FA instead to your google authenticator or authy.